# How to force an application to use the gtk theme?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, gtk3

I recently installed Visual Studio Code. The font used by the application is very Microsoft-ish. How can I force the application to use the gtk theme, in order to get a consistent font?

Answer (score 0):

VSCode is not a GTK+ application, so you cannot force it to use the GTK+ theme at all. It is an Electron application (that is, it's a webapp running inside a custom build of the Chromium browser engine).

You can however, [make a theme for VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes) if you wish, which matches the rest of your system. Though, this does seem to be limited in what can be themed.